# Why deep_compare ignores fields which starts with "__"?

Tags: specman

If i have a struct with a field which starts with '__' deep_compare will ignore this field. Why?

Exmaple:

```
struct example {
    a   : uint;
    __b : uint;
};
extend sys {
    var item_1 : example = new;
    var item_2 : example = new;

    item_1.a     = 5;
    item_1.__b   = 6;

    item_2.a     = 5;
    item_2.__b   = 7;

    print deep_compare(item_1, item_2, 10); // Should return a list of 1
};
```

Comment: In general, it is preferrable not to use names started with underscore. Such names are mostly intended for internal use by Specman, and they may not behave as expected in many aspects.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that these fields are considered as Specman internal fields, I guess this is the reason it ignores it.